# Spell that mimics tha bag of holding

Tags: spells, spellcasting

is there a spell that mimics a bag of holding? i got this idea from reading american gods, where the character "Mad Sweeney" can take small-ish objects (mostly coins but he has put bigger objects inside, like a spear). is there a spell that mimics this idea? thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site—we answer questions about thousands of different games here. What game are you playing? Each game, and each edition of a game, is going to have a different list of spells, which may or may not include a spell like this. Please add the appropriate tag for your game to the question, e.g. dnd-5e for the latest edition of Dungeons & Dragons. (If you are having difficulty finding the tag for the game you’re playing, feel free to add its name and edition to the question, or in a comment, and we’ll help you find the tag.)